# Прокаченная система обмена сообщениями на сайте?

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго времени суток! вот хочу написать хорошую систему обмена сообщениями на сайте на подобии как в ВК - есть у меня гипотиза как это реализовать но в ней пара неясных моментоов) Давайте подумаем и разберем вместе!)
Вопервых будет скрипт на странице меседжера - который заглдывает в Mysql и проверяет есть ли там таблицы именованные "idнаш+idдруга" и наоборот, если нет то при начинании беседы скрипт создает такую таблицу если она имеется то грузит из нее переписку. и таких таблиц со временем создастся уйма на каждый диалог 2х пользователей. 
и пара моментов которые меня интересуют - как сделать так что бы страница была интерективна - задавать ей обновляться каждые пару секунд? или обновлять только ее участок?
и 2е стоит ли это вобще реализовывать на PHP и mysql - может стоит на другом чемнибудь писать??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ВК работает по XMPP, то есть jabber. Для этого необходим свой сервер жабки (jabber) и что-то для работы с ним, может тут посмотрите http://habrahabr.ru/post/69693/ . ИМХО, jabber - хороший подход к данному дельцу=).

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно смотреть в сторону [Comet](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(программирование)). Желательно статью читать на английском, она более полная. А если погуглить то можно найти готовые решения, включая PHP.